# Playing sound on Hover with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, html5-audio

I'm attempting to play a sound on hover for content loaded via Ajax based on the "overlapping" method found here: http://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/:

```
function audioController(){
$("a") // loop each menu item
  .each(function(i) {
    if (i != 0) { // only clone if more than one needed
      $("#hover")
        .clone()
        .attr("id", "hover-" + i)
        .appendTo($(this).parent());
    }
    $(this).data("beeper", i); // save reference
  })
  .mouseenter(function() {
    $("#hover-" + $(this).data("beeper"))[0].play();
  });
$("#hover").attr("id", "hover-0"); // get first one into naming convention
}
```

This works for all non-ajax hrefs. However, for Ajax content, it only works for the very first href in the ajax content. I receive this error message:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'play' of undefined`
which would be this line:

`$("#hover-" + $(this).data("beeper"))[0].play();`

Here is how I am attempting to load the function with my Ajax call:

```
    $("#site-nav .nav1").on("click", function(event) {
    $('ul.top-level').load('assets/includes/recent.php', function(){
        $(this).show();
        audioController();
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I suggest learning this just for learning purposes, but please don't ever use it in the real world

Comment: Oh, the actual sound? Well, there's an on/off button.

Comment: I hate it when sites do that.

Comment: I agree...please consider making the sound "off" by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomend you to try the SoundManager2 for HTML5.

You can find it [here](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) with samples.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what I started doing.